# Странное поведение React компилятора

Tags: reactjs, webpack, компиляция

Делаю проект на `ReactJS`. Поставил модуль `reactstrap` для элементов из `bootstrap4`.

У меня есть табы из `reactstrap`:

```
   <div className="modal-body">

        <Nav pills justified>

            <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                    className={classNames({ active: this.state.activeTab === 'signInTab' })}
                    onClick={() => { this.toggle('signInTab'); }}>
                    Авторизация
                </NavLink>
            </NavItem>

            <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                    className={classNames({ active: this.state.activeTab === 'signUpTab' })}
                    onClick={() => {this.toggle('signUpTab')}}>
                    Регистрация
                </NavLink>
            </NavItem>

            <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                    className={classNames({ active: this.state.activeTab === 'termsTab' })}
                    onClick={this.openTermsTab}>
                    Правила сервиса
                </NavLink>
            </NavItem>

        </Nav>

        <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>

            <TabPane tabId={"signInTab"}>
                <hr/>
                <Form>

                    <div className="form-group input-group">

                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                <InputGroupText>
                                    <i className="fas fa-envelope"/>
                                </InputGroupText>
                            </InputGroupAddon>
                            <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </InputGroup>

                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group input-group">

                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                <InputGroupText>
                                    <i className="fas fa-unlock-alt"/>
                                </InputGroupText>
                            </InputGroupAddon>
                            <Input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" />
                        </InputGroup>

                    </div>

                    <Row>

                        <Col widths={["6"]}>
                            <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <Input
                                    type={"checkbox"}
                                    name={"rememberMe"}
                                    id={"singInTabRememberMe"}
                                    className={"custom-control-input"}/>
                                <Label
                                    for={"singInTabRememberMe"}
                                    className={"custom-control-label"}>
                                    запомнить меня
                                </Label>
                            </div>
                        </Col>

                        <Col widths={["6"]} className="text-center pl-0 pr-0">
                            <Link to="/admin/forgot" className="brand-link">
                                Не помню пароль
                            </Link>
                        </Col>

                    </Row>

                    <Button color="" className={"float-right brand-nav-btn left-filling"}>
                        <i><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/login2.png'} alt=""/></i>
                        <span>
                            Вход
                        </span>
                    </Button>

                </Form>
            </TabPane>

            <TabPane tabId={"signUpTab"}>
                <hr/>
                <Form>

                    <div className="form-group input-group">

                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                <InputGroupText>
                                    <i className="fas fa-envelope"/>
                                </InputGroupText>
                            </InputGroupAddon>
                            <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </InputGroup>

                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group input-group">

                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                <InputGroupText>
                                    <i className="fas fa-unlock-alt"/>
                                </InputGroupText>
                            </InputGroupAddon>
                            <Input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" />
                        </InputGroup>

                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group input-group">

                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                <InputGroupText>
                                    <i className="fas fa-unlock-alt"/>
                                </InputGroupText>
                            </InputGroupAddon>
                            <Input type="password" placeholder="Повторите пароль" />
                        </InputGroup>

                    </div>

                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox ">

                        <Input
                            type={"checkbox"}
                            name={"example1"}
                            id={"chBxTermsArgee"}
                            className={"custom-control-input"}/>

                        <Label
                            for={"chBxTermsArgee"}
                            className={"custom-control-label"}>

                            согласен с

                            <a href={"#"} className="brand-link" id="serviceTermsLink"
                               onClick={this.openTermsTab}>
                                 правилами сервиса
                            </a>

                        </Label>

                    </div>

                    <Button color="" className={"float-right brand-nav-btn left-filling"}>
                        <i><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/login2.png'} alt=""/></i>
                        <span>
                            Отправить
                        </span>
                    </Button>

                </Form>

            </TabPane>

            <TabPane id="termsTab" tabId={"termsTab"}>
                <hr/>
                <div className="service-terms">
                    <h3>Правила предоставления услуги</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ipsa, cumque
                        necessitatibus impedit delectus ratione harum nisi nemo
                        minus eaque,
                        exercitationem consequuntur. Repellat tempore molestias
                        dicta. Recusandae
                        quam rem ducimus temporibus!
                        Doloribus quibusdam ullam atque possimus sequi libero
                        inventore natus amet
                        facilis, minima dolore molestias accusantium nam omnis,
                        delectus totam fuga
                        quae nemo asperiores laboriosam veritatis! Ipsam aperiam
                        ipsa nulla vitae?
                        Temporibus nulla rem aspernatur eum quidem minima
                        voluptatum corporis libero
                        explicabo. Impedit distinctio deleniti labore
                        exercitationem quae
                        repudiandae consequatur? Ullam eveniet quo
                        exercitationem! Sint ab, nihil
                        placeat ea omnis libero!
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Cum, voluptatum
                        perspiciatis molestias reiciendis blanditiis pariatur in
                        sunt velit? Labore
                        assumenda repellendus sint molestiae debitis esse itaque
                        totam distinctio
                        perferendis reiciendis?
                    </p>
                </div>

            </TabPane>

        </TabContent>

    </div>
```

Так все работает. 
Я захотел перенести контент для табов в отдельные компоненты.

И вот тут при компиляции возникла ошибка:

```
./node_modules/reactstrap/src/Alert.js
SyntaxError: E:\IDEA\application\node_modules\reactstrap\src\Alert.js: Unexpected token (72:4)

  70 | 
  71 |   return (
> 72 |     <Fade {...attributes} {...alertTransition} tag={Tag} className={classes} in={isOpen} role="alert" innerRef={innerRef}>
     |     ^
  73 |       {toggle ?
  74 |         <button type="button" className={closeClasses} aria-label={closeAriaLabel} onClick={toggle}>
  75 |           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
```

Почему?

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "front-end-react-v1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.6.2",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.2.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-native": "^4.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `import React from 'react'` и `import Fade from './..'` есть?

Comment: Где есть? Это ошибка происходит в файле не моего модуля, то бишь уже написанного. Я файл Alert.js даже не использую нигде.

Comment: Вроде бы нужно поставить еще и `bootstrap` пакет (берите версию 4.1.3), а также нужно выполнить импорт стилей в главном индексном файле `src/index.js` вот так: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` Пакеты `react` и `react-dom` у вас есть.

Comment: @DenisBubnov он нужен чисто для стилей. Ставил уже - все равно такая беда.

Comment: @Tsyklop да, я понимаю, странная какая-то ошибка в глубинах самого `reactstrap`. А ссылку (`<script ...></script> `) на reactstrap бибилиотеку вы добавили, может дело в какой-то мелочи.